# How to authenticate user with LDAP using xml config file ,JAVA, Spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, ldap

My program "to authenticate an user with LDAP" (listed in appendix) works fine when using JNDI.

According to requirement, I have to use spring-security and config file ( contains ldap info) in xml format ( idlf file is not allowed).

**I am looking for a code snippet in JAVA ( I am using 1.8 and spring) that will use this  Ldap.xml file to pull up all relevant info for java to authenticate an user. Need to use spring-security.**

May I get any help on that?

**LDAP.xml looks like :**

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>


      <!-- The  Security Module.  This module will authenticate against AD
           and determine authorization against the SECURITY_OWNER schema
      -->

      <application-policy name="something-targeting">
        <authentication>
           <login-module code="com.et.security.ETLoginModule" flag="required" >        
              <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldap://pcocpwdom01.corp.something.com:389</module-option>
              <module-option name="bindDN">CN=SVCLdapQry,OU=ServiceAccounts_Admins,OU=Data Services,DC=corp,DC=something,DC=com</module-option>
              <module-option name="bindCredential">+byZB0ocHUQL0MDhd2mN3dSjskf2S7ff2hiCcCDThSE=</module-option>
              <module-option name="baseCtxDN">DC=corp,DC=something,DC=com</module-option>
              <module-option name="baseFilter">(samaccountname={0})</module-option>
              <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>

           </login-module>
        </authentication>
      </application-policy>
```

**looking for something like :**

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource().ldif("classpath:LDAP.xml");
}
```

Any help is appreciated.Please let me know if more information is required.

I tried examples from :

- http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

could not make work any of them.

**Appendix A:**

```
    package com.something.online.ice.ui.authentication;

    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
    import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
    import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
    import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
    import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;


    /**
     * 

     * This is a solution that can be used to authenticate a user with something else than the DN, for example with a uid or sAMAccountName.

        The steps to do are:

        -Connect to the LDAP server
        -Authenticate with a service user of whom we know the DN and credentials
        -Search for the user you want to authenticate, search him with some attribute (for example sAMAccountName)
        -Get the DN of the user we found
        -Open another connection to the LDAP server with the found DN and the password
        -If the user is found and authentication works, you are fine

     *
     */

    public class LdapAuthManagerJNDI 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            LdapAuthManagerJNDI mgr = new LdapAuthManagerJNDI();
            System.out.println(mgr.authenticateUsr("svc_oapusr", "pswd"));

        }

        public boolean authenticateUsr(String usrName, String pswd)
        {


            Hashtable<String, String> serviceEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            boolean authenticationresullt = false;


            serviceEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            serviceEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://pcocpwdom01.corp.something.com:389");

            serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=SVCLdapQry,OU=ServiceAccounts_Admins,OU=Data Services,DC=corp,DC=something,DC=com"); 
            serviceEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "ADR0cks!~");

            // Create the initial context

            DirContext serviceCtx;
            try 
            {
                serviceCtx = new InitialDirContext(serviceEnv);
            } 
            catch (NamingException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            boolean serviceConnectionResult = serviceCtx != null;

            if(serviceConnectionResult)
            {
                System.out.println("LDAP basic authorization is successful");
            }

            // user to authenticate
            String identifyingAttribute = "samaccountname";
            String ldapUrl = "ldap://pcocpwdom01.corp.something.com:389";
            String base = "DC=corp,DC=something,DC=com";

            // we don't need all attributes, just let it get the identifying one
            String[] attributeFilter = { identifyingAttribute };
            SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
            sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
            sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

         // use a search filter to find only the user we want to authenticate
            String searchFilter = "(" + identifyingAttribute + "=" + usrName + ")";

            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

            try 
            {
                results = serviceCtx.search(base, searchFilter, sc);
            } 
            catch (NamingException e1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            DirContext usrCtx = null;
            try {
                if (results.hasMore()) {
                    // get the users DN (distinguishedName) from the result
                    SearchResult result = results.next();
                    String distinguishedName = result.getNameInNamespace();

                    // attempt another authentication, now with the user
                    Properties authEnv = new Properties();
                    authEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
                    authEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
                    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, distinguishedName);
                    authEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pswd);
                    usrCtx = new InitialDirContext(authEnv);

                    System.out.println("Authentication successful");
                    authenticationresullt =  true;
                }
            } catch (NamingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


          //close the service context
            if(usrCtx != null)
                try 
                {
                    usrCtx.close();
                } 
                catch (NamingException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }


            //close the service context
            if(serviceCtx != null)
                try 
                {
                    serviceCtx.close();
                } 
                catch (NamingException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }

            return authenticationresullt;


        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed :

- https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-security-active-directory-ldap-example/
- https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

to implement "Spring Security Active Directory LDAP Example
Spring Security Active Directory LDAP ".